# Overriten script in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I overwrote my Stored Procedure with a old script by mistake.
I dont want to re code everything again.

Is there any way I can get the old Stored Procedure script?

Comment: Do you have backups of your database?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a backup of the database, it will contain the stored procedures that were in the DB at the time of the backup. You can restore it to another DB or server and get the code from there.

Answer (score 0):

Extract it from a backup of your database. That's about it, i'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to restore it from a backup.